# How to use `yq` to select key-value pairs and format them into "$key=$value" style outputs?

Tags: bash, jq, yq

Let say I have YAML file that looks like this:

```
FOO: somefoo
BAR: somebar
```

I would like to convert this (using `yq`) into the following so that I can source the contents into environment variables:

```
export BAR='somebar'
export FOO='somefoo'
```

I can do it it with `jq` by converting the input to JSON first, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it with `yq` only. (I am using `yq` 4.x, <4.18).

So, concretely, how could I do the following using just `yq`?

```
INPUT="FOO: somefoo
BAR: somebar"

echo "$INPUT" | yq e 'to_json' - | jq -r 'keys[] as $k | "export \($k)='\''\(.[$k])'\''"'
```

Comment: This is not possible with the existing Go yq constructs off the shelf

Answer (score 5):

You could switch to kislyuk's [yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) which uses native jq under the hood. Then, you would just need [`to_entries`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries%2Cfrom_entries%2Cwith_entries) to access key and value, [string interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation-%5C%28foo%29) in combination with the `-r` flag to produce the output, and [`@sh`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Formatstringsandescaping) to escape for shell compliance:

```sh
yq -r 'to_entries[] | "export \(.key)=\(.value | @sh)"'
```

```
export FOO='somefoo'
export BAR='somebar'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `@sh` operator has been added in [`yq v4.31.1`](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/tag/v4.31.1) (with [my humble contribution](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues/1526)). Now you can do it pretty much the same way as in `jq`:

```bash
yq '.[] | "export " + key + "=" + @sh'
```

The quoting algorithm is a bit different from `jq` as it starts to quote only at characters that need quoting, so the literal output will likely differ, but will be later parsed equally.

```yaml
# input
FOO: somefoo
BAR: somebar and some
```

```bash
# result
export FOO=somefoo
export BAR=somebar' and some'
```

---

With **older `yq` versions** you can still implement a primitive but safe quoting algorithm using other `yq` functions (the quoting is a little lovely nightmare, though):

```bash
# POSIX shell quoting starting "
yq ".[] | \"export \" + key + \"='\" + sub(\"'\", \"'\''\") + \"'\""
# POSIX shell quoting starting '
yq '.[] | "export " + key + "='\''" + sub("'\''", "'\'\\\'\''") + "'\''"'
# BASH "dollar" quoting
yq $'.[] | "export " + key + "=\'" + sub("\'", "\'\\\'\'") + "\'"'
```

Actually this is exactly [what `jq` does](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/jq-1.6/src/builtin.c#L617-L619) with its `@sh`. In all cases this ends up as:

```bash
export FOO='somefoo'
export BAR='somebar and some'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `key` operator and string concatenation:

```bash
$ echo "$INPUT" | yq $'.[] | "export " + key + "=\'" + . + "\'"'
export FOO='somefoo'
export BAR='somebar'
```

Tested with `yq` 4.27.2

Comment: This will break for a value containing single quotes.